# Modelling and Sculpting

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, sculpting

I have an image of a packet and I want to model it with exact same wrinkles at exact same place.Sculpting manually takes a lot of time.Is there any other way?
Attaching the image below
[image]

Comment: if you have an orthophoto you can try a bump or displace node. If you do it manually it's the best choice

Comment: The image does not contain enough information about the bags 3d dimensional properties. If you want it to be a copy of the object without doing it manually then I recommend reading up on photogrammetry. I may or may not be worth the effort depending on how much of these tasks you plan to do.

Comment: You could try box modelling the big folds and then adding a displacement modifier with a cloud texture for the micro detail and then in sculpt mode, it'll only need touching up, smoothing areas out adding little bumps here and there. However, looking up similar types of material might find you a nice image to greyscale in photoshop or GIMP to use as a more accurate displacement map for your displacement modifier. Fromt his image, it's difficult to do anything because it's not flat and would require heavy editing in photoshop to get a nice displacement map.